# Retrieve release ID from Github release tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, github-api

I'm gathering some Github releases using `requests` for Python 3.
The Github API mentions that to get a specific release, you need its ID. Is there a way to only use the tag to do so, or in the worst case to use it to retrieve the ID?

Here's my code so far:

```
    def getGithub(self, url=ulgit.RELEASES_URL):
        """Get Github information"""

        headers = {"Authorization": f"token {ulgit.TOKEN}"}
        session = requests.Session()
        response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
        content = response.text
        data = json.loads(content)

        return data

    def getVersionsGithub(self):
        """Get available versions releases on Github"""

        list_releases = []
        for i in self.getGithub():
            list_releases.append(i["tag_name"])
    
    def getSpecificRelease(self):
        #TODO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GitHub's GraphQL API to get a release by the tag name.

As a (random) example:

```
{
  repository(owner: "pytorch", name: "pytorch") {
    release(tagName: "v1.11.0") {
      databaseId
      createdAt
    }
  }
}
```

You can try it out in the browser [here](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer)

Or from the command line:

```
curl https://api.github.com/graphql -X POST -H "Authorization: bearer token" -d '
 {
  "query": "query { repository ( owner: \"pytorch\", name: \"pytorch\" ) { release ( tagName: \"v1.11.0\" ) { databaseId createdAt }} }"
 }
'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using the `zipball_url` given by the API to download a specific release by tag name